# Using Script manager causes the page to load slowly

Tags: asp.net

I use script manager in website to use ajax, but when I host my page it loads very slowly.
When I remove the script manager it loads quickly. 
So what I have to do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The script manager has some significant amount of JavaScript (up to 100K) to be loaded. What you can do to remedy the problem is to set up proper caching policy, so that the browser only loads it once and takes it from the cache after the first load

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that debugging is disabled.  More script and round-trips are needed in debug mode.